# Sending response to client from within the request.post callback in koa

Tags: node.js, routes, koa

I have this koa route `/landing` which is resulting in 404.

```
function* landing() {
    //this.body = "response"; //1
    var request = require('request');
    request.post('http://url.com/resource',
    { json: { key: "post data"} },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var token = body.data;
            getListByToken(token, function(list){
                this.body = list; //2
            });
        }
    });
}
```

See comment in the top `//1` - that is how you define body of a response in koa in a route. Instead of `//1` I want to send response from `//2` i.e. from within that request.get.

When a user is routed to `/landing` a post request has to fetch some data from a url. That fetched data is to be used by `getListByToken` to bring some other data, `list`, which should be sent to the user. The above code should have worked but it results in `404` `Not Found` response by koa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `q`. It makes koa hold response until yield happens.

```
var q = require('q');
function* landing() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var request = require('request');
    request.post('http://url.com/resource',
    { json: { key: "post data"} },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var token = body.data;
            getListByToken(token, function(list){
                deferred.resolve(repolist);
            });
       }
    });
    this.body = yield deferred.promise;
}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159513/1128379

Answer (score 2):

We can use promises, simple and clean way of managing asynchronous codes.

```
var request = require('request-promise');

. . .

function* landing() {
  try {
    let response = yield request( {
      method: 'POST',,
      url: 'http://url.com/resource',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify( { json: { key: "post data"} } )
    } );

    this.body = yield new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
      if ( response.statusCode == 200 ) {
        getListByToken( response.body.token, function( list ) {
          resolve( list );
        } );
      }
    } );
  } catch ( err ) {
    /* do something with your errors */
  }
}
```